# Check progress on already running fsck process

Tags: ubuntu, fsck

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get e2fsck to show progress information?](https://serverfault.com/questions/118791/how-do-you-get-e2fsck-to-show-progress-information)

Is there a way to check the progress of fsck.ext3 under Ubuntu, if I'm logged in remotely?

Obviously the time taken depends on a lot of factors, but if fsck has to option of displaying a progress bar, it should be possible

Clarification: The fsck process has already been started in another terminal (at startup), and I need to view the progress from remote machine. Running fsck with the -C flag is therefore not the answer. I was hoping for a log file that I could look at (/var/log/fsck/* are empty).

Comment: If you edit your question to show how it's not an exact dupe, it stands a chance of being reopened.

Comment: After your edits, it's still a duplicate. The answer you're after is at  http://serverfault.com/questions/118791/how-do-you-get-e2fsck-to-show-progress-information/118792#118792

Answer (score 0):

Try `fsck -C`, it displays progress on every step of checking (but not the total one)